# Удалить элемент ListView из фрагмента

Tags: java, android

Как передать данные из фрагмента в активити для удаления элемента ListView? номер элемента мне известен (был получен во фрагменте через Bundle).Метод ((MainActivity)getActivity()) - тут не прокатывает.

Comment: Почему не прокатывает, список и фрагмент в разных `Activity`?

Comment: Я поитогу просто сделал класс фрагмента в файле в котором активити, и все намного проще стало. Но подозреваю что это непроффесионально и вопрос остается актуальным на будущее. Через метод ((MainActivity)getActivity()) у меня получалось сослаться на массив и удалить из него, но не получалось обновить адаптер (adapt.notifyDatasetChanged())

Comment: Просто в своей `MainActivity` создайте метод, в котором и выполняйте нужные действия, а из фрагмента этот метод вызывайте. Методу в активити будут доступны все её поля и методы (в том числе приватные).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно делать через `interface`.

Во фрагменте:

```
public interface DeleteItem {
    void deleteItem(int position)
}

DeleteItem deleteItem;

@Override //метод для API 23+
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        deleteItem = (DeleteItem) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override //метод для API < 23
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        deleteItem = (DeleteItem) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    deleteItem = null;    
}
```

В активити:

```
MainActivity implements MyFragment.DeleteItem

void deleteItem (int position){
    ...удаление/если надо, обновление адаптера
}
```

Вызывать во фрагменте: `deleteItem.deleteItem(position);`